# Laravel validating required at least one element in array

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I am trying to post the following data to an endpoint built up on Laravel.

```
{
  "category": "2",
  "title": "my text goes here",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "correct": {
    "id": "NULL",
    "text": "Correct"
  },
  "wrong": [
    {
      "id": "NULL",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "NULL",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "NULL",
      "text": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

and I have the following validation rules.

```
return [
    'correct'      => 'required|array',
    'correct.text' => 'required',
    'wrong'        => 'required|array|between:1,3'
];
```

What I am trying to accomplish is the `wrong`  should be and array and it should contain at least one element and should not exceed 3. Now these rules are satisfying, but there is one more case I need to take care and that  is the validation of the `text` in `wrong` . With the current rules, if I post the above data, it will accept as there is no rule in place for the `text` in the `wrong` section. Which rule I need to add to validate that the `wrong` section at least contains one entry with a not empty text.

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

If you have very specific needs for a validator rule, you can always [create your own](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#custom-validation-rules).

### Create a Custom Validator

The scheme will be: `properties_filled:propertyName:minimumOccurence`. This rule will check if the field under validation:

- Is an array.
- Its elements have at least `minimumOccurence` amounts of **non empty** (`!== ''`) values among element properties called `propertyName`.

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file's `boot` method, you can add the custom rule implementation:

```php
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('properties_filled', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $validatedProperty = $parameters[0];
        $minimumOccurrence = $parameters[1];

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $validElementCount = 0;
            $valueCount = count($value);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $valueCount; ++$i) {
                if ($value[$i][$validatedProperty] !== '') {
                    ++$validElementCount;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return $validElementCount >= $minimumOccurrence;
    });
}
```

Then you can use it in your validation like this:

```php
return [
    'correct'      => 'required|array',
    'correct.text' => 'required',
    'wrong'        => 'required|between:1,3|properties_filled:text,1'
];
```

### Testing

**Note:** I assumed that you parse your JSON data with [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s `$assoc` parameter set to `true`. If you use an object then change the `$value[$i][$validatedProperty] !== ''` in the condition to: `$value[$i]->{$validatedProperty} !== ''`.

Here is my example test:

```php
$data = json_decode('{"category":"2","title":"mytextgoeshere","difficulty":1,"correct":{"id":"NULL","text":"Correct"},"wrong":[{"id":"NULL","text":""},{"id":"NULL","text":""},{"id":"NULL","text":""}]}', true);
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'correct'      => 'required|array',
    'correct.text' => 'required',
    'wrong'        => 'required|between:1,3|properties_filled:text,1'
]);
$validator->fails();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the [validation rule `in`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-in)

EDIT: I assume that wrong will have a specific value, therefore pass that value in this way

```
return [
    'correct'      => 'required|array',
    'correct.text' => 'required',
    'wrong'        => 'required|array|between:1,3',
    'wrong.text'   => 'sometimes|min:1|in:somevalue,someothervalue',
];
```

The `sometimes` validation makes sure that field is checked only if exists. To check that there will be at least

I'm not sure, but does [`min`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-min) suffice to your request? Otherwise you have to write a custom validation rule as someone else suggested

Comment: Can you please elaborate, how can I use it ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while trying to validate an array on the API side. I made a solution. try this

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'target_user_ids' => 'required',
            'target_user_ids.*' => 'present|exists:users,uuid|distinct',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'error' => $validator->errors()->first(),
            ], 400);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to validate input fields in array, you can define your rules like this:

```
return [
    'correct'      => 'required|array',
    'correct.text' => 'required',
    'wrong'        => 'required|array|between:1,3',
    'wrong.*.text' => 'required|string|min:1',
];
```

Comment: This will not work as it will check for all the elements in `wrong` section. I only need atleast one non empty value there for `text`

Comment: @Happy Coder You can create a service provider to register a custom validation rule.